# Typescript error on ionic project version 3 created with current ionic 4(5.4.13) CLI

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

Here is the error message, after running `ionic serve`

```
Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'unknown'.
home/jurr/node_modules/@types/graphql-upload/index.d.ts
```

I have setup with nvm `( node v12.13.1, npm 6.12.1 )`.
I'm trying to start ionic 3 generated app with current CLI:

```
/home/jurr/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.1/lib
├── cordova@9.0.0
├── ionic@5.4.13
└── npm@6.12.1
```

Typescript and ionic version:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
 },
```

Comment: which is the output when you run (npm audit)?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Verthon/c3265ff82efc06531628aeed7014ef94

Comment: See if this thread helps you: https://github.com/vfile/vfile-message/issues/3

Comment: Updated typescript to "typescript": "^3.2.4" seems to work ok, for now. Haven't tested fully it tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case problem was solved by updating typescript version to `^3.2.4`:
`npm install typescript@3.2.4`